# How to test child React component created in Render with React.createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a custom react element built on top of some ad-hoc React elements
Code:

```
return (
    React.createElement("div", {className: classes},
        React.createElement(TextField, {  
            ref: "omniTextBox",
            className: "menu-textfield",
            onChange: this._onControlChange
        }),
    )
);
```

this._onControlChange manipulates state based on textfield value. It is what I want to test, with different input to the textfield triggering different state of component.

Jest code:

```
var customComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument( <CustomField /> );
var customField = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(customComponent, customField);
TestUtils.Simulate.change(customField, {target: {value: 'Hello, world'}});
```

I tried to mock function for _onControlChange to see if it is called, it is called 0 times. I also tried to see state of the customField var before and after simulate() call, and nothing changes. I wonder if I am missing something to simulate typing in a text field

I have tried all of the options to select by tag, type and class to no success. I can see the textfield element when console.log the rendered component. Is there any way to grab an instance of TextField via the ref?

Comment: The change event is handled on the `TextField` component, though, not the `customField`, right? I would try `findRenderedComponentWithType(..., TextField)` instead. One other thing to keep in mind is that in React 0.12+, you need to use `<InitialCapitals>` in custom JSX components or JSX treats them as HTML (so `<CustomField />` instead of `<customField />`)

Comment: @BinaryMuse my code follows initialcapitals, my bad on making up the code for the question. That didn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have misused [`TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html#findrenderedcomponentwithtype). The input field in your custom component is actually a `TextField`.

```
var txtField = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(customComponent, TextField);
TestUtils.Simulate.change(txtField, {target: {value: 'Hello, world'}});
```

You were also redefining `customField`, thus why I changed the variable name here.

Comment: Tried again with withTag, withClass, etc...not able to find the child component at all. Is there any way to inspect the rendered react doc to see the rendered HTML in jest?

Comment: 'findRenderedComponentWithType' misspelled as 'findRenderedDOMComponentWithType' in sample code. Could not modify as edit has to have atleast 6 chars changed.

Comment: @VigneshManogar Thank you for pointing out the mistake, it's now fixed. Changes to code are best suggested with a comment first, as you did here.